# How to run chromedriver on linux server?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, rhel

I am trying to run selenium test case with chromedriver on a server running Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago).

Whenever I try to run command to check to driver is running fine or not by -

```
./chromedriver
```

then I get an error:

```
./chromedriver: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by ./chromedriver)
./chromedriver: /usr/lib64/libnss3.so: version `NSS_3.14.3' not found (required by ./chromedriver)
```

How to resolve it ?

Comment: What is the exact OS that you running on the server? Is it CentOS?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)

Comment: Is the chromedriver version the last available?

Comment: You should [edit] the question to provide *all* relevant details. Replying in comments means that not everyone will see important information. See also: [ask].